# How to parse Timezone Offset string?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, offset

I retrieve a value from my database of a timeZone offset. The value that I get is in time.

For example, it could be `"-5:00"`, `"+7:30"`, `"+3:00"`, etc.

How do I convert that to a double so I can do an `AddHours()` call on a `DateTime` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var time = "+7:30";
time = time.Replace("+", "");  // Remove the + if it is there.

var hours = TimeSpan.Parse(time).TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 7):

[John Koerner answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27301160/447156) have a few cons;

- Based on `+` or `-`, additional string operations *might* be needed. It can handle `-` or no sign, but it can't handle `+` character itself.
- Since his used `TimeSpan.Parse(string)` overload, if [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`TimeSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `:` (*I know it's rare*) this method throws `FormatException`.

Besides on these, I think `TimeSpan.Parse` is not the best way to parse an [UTC Offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). Indeed an `Offset` is also a time interval, but this value *might* not be always parsed successfully.

I think the best option is [`DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tryparseexact.aspx) with [`zzz` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier). Since [`DateTimeOffset.Offset` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.offset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns it's value as `TimeSpan`, it is perfectly can be use with `DateTime`.

For example;

```
var s = "+05:30";
DateTimeOffset dto;
var dtop = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "zzz",
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                 DateTimeStyles.None, out dto);
var today = DateTime.Today;
today = today.AddHours(dto.Offset.TotalHours);
```

This works for these [UTC Offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) formats (`±[hh]:[mm]`, `±[hh][mm]`).